# Grid lines for custom log scales

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the example below, some `ExtremeValue` data is seen to be linear on a linear vs. log-log plot. Is it possible to generate the grid lines as seen in the left figure of the following code, by applying a custom axis scaling? So far as I know there is no `xmode=loglog` or some such thing,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{filecontents*}{ExtremeValue.dat}
0 0.331154277152909
11.1111111111111 0.69502009750662
22.2222222222222 0.887128720985134
33.3333333333333 0.961341225207159
44.4444444444444 0.987105143707509
55.5555555555556 0.995736611644397
66.6666666666667 0.998594510759846
77.7777777777778 0.999537104517995
88.8888888888889 0.999847594388806
100 0.999949826576672
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, ymode=log, axis lines=left, grid=both, grid style={draw=black!10},]
        \addplot[domain=1:100, samples=100] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=left, grid=both, grid style={draw=black!10},]
        \addplot[solid] table[x index={0}, y expr=-ln(-ln(\thisrowno{1}))] {ExtremeValue.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install more or less arbitrary coordinate transformations. This is described in section **4.21 Symbolic Coordinates and User Transformations** of pgfplots manual v1.17. Here is an example of the type `loglog`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{filecontents*}{ExtremeValue.dat}
0 0.331154277152909
11.1111111111111 0.69502009750662
22.2222222222222 0.887128720985134
33.3333333333333 0.961341225207159
44.4444444444444 0.987105143707509
55.5555555555556 0.995736611644397
66.6666666666667 0.998594510759846
77.7777777777778 0.999537104517995
88.8888888888889 0.999847594388806
100 0.999949826576672
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, ymode=log, axis lines=left, grid=both, grid style={draw=black!10},]
        \addplot[domain=1:100, samples=100] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=left, grid=both, grid style={draw=black!10},
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{-ln(-ln(#1))}},
    y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{exp(-exp(-#1))}},
    ytick={0.37,0.57,...,1}
    ]
        \addplot[solid] table[x index={0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {ExtremeValue.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In case people want to have finer grid lines without overlapping labels, you can do something like `ytick={0.1,0.2,...,1}` and `yticklabels={0.1,,,,0.5,,,,1}`.

Comment: @algae Good point, thanks!